# Помогите реализовать поиск по номеру без пробелов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, веб-программирование

С бека приходят данные для поиска в которых есть номер паспорта содержащий в себе пробелы "#05 17 471424" и если вводить идентично с пробелами, то все находит, а если ввести без пробелов "#0517471424", то не находит, а нужно чтобы находил. Помогите)
PS:
Для поиска по паспорту используется символ "#" или "№"

```js
$(function () {

    /**
     *
     * @param {Object} obj
     * @param {string} obj.selectorForFilter - Селектор по которому будет производится фильрация
     * @param {string} obj.inputSelector - Селектор инпута, в котором производится фильтрация
     * @param {string} obj.selectorForHide - Селектор в который обернуты элементы по которым производится фильтрация. Этот селектор будет скрываться, если не совпадает с введенным значением
     */
    function searchFilter(obj) {
        var items = document.querySelectorAll(obj.selectorForFilter),
            input = document.querySelector(obj.inputSelector);

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];

            if (item.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(input.value.trim().replace(/[#№]/g, ' ').toUpperCase()) > -1) {
                item.closest(obj.selectorForHide).style.display = "";
                item.closest(obj.selectorForHide).classList.add('active-search-item');

            }
            else {
                item.closest(obj.selectorForHide).style.display = "none";
                item.closest(obj.selectorForHide).classList.remove('active-search-item');
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).on('keyup', '.t-search', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        if ($(this).val()[0] === "#" || $(this).val()[0] === "№") {
            searchFilter({
                selectorForFilter: '.search-select li .account-passport',
                inputSelector: '.t-search',
                selectorForHide: 'li'
            });
        } else if ($.isNumeric($(this).val()[0])) {
            searchFilter({
                selectorForFilter: '.search-select li .account-number',
                inputSelector: '.t-search',
                selectorForHide: 'li'
            });
        } else {
            searchFilter({
                selectorForFilter: '.search-select li .account-owner',
                inputSelector: '.t-search',
                selectorForHide: 'li'
            });
        }
        if (e.key === 'Enter' &&  $(this).siblings('.search-select')[0].querySelector('.active-search-item') !== null) {
            $(this).siblings('.search-select')[0].querySelector('.active-search-item').click();
        }

    });


 
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Текст" class="t-search mass-search">
<ul class="search-select" style="dispay:"none" ">
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358050001</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
ООО "Финанс Групп" (ИНН                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        7745002141
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№3</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358010001</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
Корнилов Роман Семенович (Паспорт гражданина РФ                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        45 03 125345
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№4</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358010002</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
Сиротин Павел Петрович (Паспорт гражданина РФ                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        14 01 334355
                                    </span>
), Зверева Мария Сергеевна (Паспорт гражданина РФ                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        14 01 114355
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№5</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358050002</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
Колчев Дмитрий Сергеевич (Паспорт гражданина РФ                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        05 17 471424
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№6</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358050002</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
ОАО "Алмаз" (ИНН                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        7733223554
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№7</span>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <span class="account-number">358050003</span>
                            <span class="account-owner">
ФАУГИ (ИНН                                     <span class="account-passport">
                                        7700111111
                                    </span>
),                             </span>
                            <span class="account-register">рег.№8</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удалить пробелы из строки?

```
if (item.innerHTML.toUpperCase().replace(/\s+/g, '').indexOf(input.value.trim().replace(/[#№]/g, ' ').replace(/\s+/g, '').toUpperCase()) > -1) {...
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает )